# Selecting all TRs where a specific TD contains specific text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to select all rows where a cell in a specific location contains a specific value.

example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>MO</td>
    <td>MO Williams</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>PG</td>
    <td>MO Williams</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to ONLY select the rows where the 2nd  contains MO.

I've tried this:

```
     $('tr:has(td:eq(1):contains(MO))')
```

but that doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Selects all `td` elements:

```
$("tr").find("td:eq(1):contains('MO')")
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/jBbS7/

---

Selects all `tr` elements:

```
$("tr").find("td:eq(1):contains('MO')").parents("tr");
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/jBbS7/4/

Comment: @Patricia, see my 2nd selector, works more better. Take me to dinner first before you tweak my fiddle, am I right? Anyone? ....

Comment: @hunter ah yes, that's even better.  i forked it first ;)

Comment: is there a way to do it without using the .find or .parent?